# Exchange 2010 to O365 migration hcw8078

Tags: exchange, office365, migration

I'm having a problem configuring an Office 365 endpoint using HCW for migrating Exchange 2010 to O365 (mailboxes and public folders).

I have created an external and internal URL in `/ews`; I have enabled `msrproxy` but the url `https://mail.domain/ews/mrsproxy.svc` gives me this screen:

[image]

I don't know what to do with my `I thin web.config` file - what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

This message means that everything is fine and this is a normal page.

However you still need to verify the [Hybrid deployment prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/hybrid-deployment-prerequisites)

Comment: OK If this is ok second thought is certificate - external CA certyficate should be assigned to on prem exchange services like IIS - only IIS?

Comment: Not only IIS, you should also assign the new SSL certificate to POP, IMAP,SMTP services as well. You can refer to the last answer in this case:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange/Certificate-for-Hybrid-Connector/td-p/269888 What's more the official document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/certificate-requirements